# How to convert an "ArrayList<ClassNod>" written in Java into a C++ program language?

Tags: java, c++, class, arraylist

I wrote a class in Java called Nod.java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Nod {
        int[] vol;
        String op="";
        Nod parent; 
        int adancime;

        Nod (int[] vol, String op,Nod parent,int adancime){             
            this.vol=vol;
            this.op=op;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.adancime=adancime;
            }

        public String toString() {
        return op;
        }

        public int getAdancime() {
                return adancime;
        }

        public ArrayList<Nod> getCale(ArrayList<Nod> lnoduri) {
        lnoduri.add(0, this);
        if (parent != null) lnoduri = parent.getCale(lnoduri);
        return lnoduri;
        }

        public ArrayList<Nod> getCale() 
        { return(getCale(new ArrayList<Nod>())); }
}
```

and I want to rewrite it in C++ but I don't know how to rewrite these two functions in C++:

```
public ArrayList<Nod> getPath(ArrayList<Nod> lnoduri) {
    lnoduri.add(0, this);
    if (parent != null) lnoduri = parent.getPath(lnoduri);
    return lnoduri;
}

public ArrayList<Nod> getPath(){ 
    return(getPath(new ArrayList<Nod>())); 
}
```

These functions store the path of each nod to the parent.

Can you help me please?

**EDIT**

Because it is a related question, I add it here.

I wrote a function to "Vase" class in Java:

```
public ArrayList<Nod> succesori(Nod parent) {

    // "Nod" is another class.                          
    ArrayList<Nod> listTest = new ArrayList<Nod>();

    // operations/conditions;

    listTest.add(new Nod(vol,op,parent,adancime+1));
    return(listTest);
}
```

and I want to rewrite in C++:

```
vector<Nod*> Vase::succesori(Nod *parinte)
{
    vector<Nod*> *listTest = new vector<Nod*>();

    // operations/conditions;

    listTest.insert(new Nod(vol,op,parent,adancime+1)); 
    return (*listTest);
    }
```

But I get an error when I try to execut this command:
    listTest.insert(new Nod(vol,op,parent,adancime+1));

*IntelliSense: expression must have class type*

Error 1 error C2228: left of '.insert' must have class/struct/union

How can I add/insert in listTest a new Nod class?

Comment: The best way to convert something written in Java to C++ is to redesign the whole thing; the semantics and idioms of the two languages are just too different. For example, does this class have any subclasses? Does any of the subclasses override `getPath` ?

Comment: It's a bad idea to add another question to an already answered question. Still, you are mixing pointers with non-pointers. The code should look as follows: `vector<Nod*> Vase::successor(Nod* parent) { vector<Nod*> listTest; listTest.insert(new Nod(...)); return listTest; }`

Comment: Sorry because of this... I will open a new question next time. I wrote what you said and I get another errors:"Error 1 error C2661: 'std::vector<_Ty>::insert' : no overloaded function takes 1 arguments"  and  "IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Ax>::insert [with _Ty=Nod *, _Ax=std::allocator<Nod *>]" matches the argument list" and "IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call". Something is wrong with that insert...

Comment: I used "push_back" instead "insert" and it is working now. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java code looks a bit strange. If you really want to use recursion, then I recommend rewriting the methods as follows.

```
public void getCale(ArrayList<Nod> lnoduri) {
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.getCale(lnoduri);
    }
    lnoduri.add(this);
}

public ArrayList<Nod> getCale() {
    ArrayList<Nod> result = new ArrayList();
    getCale(result);
    return result;
}
```

In C++, I would use only one member function.

```
std::vector<Nod*> getCale()
{
    std::vector<Nod*> result;
    for (Nod* n = this; n; n = n->_parent) {
        result.push_back(n);
    }
    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I tried it and it is working.

Comment: I edited the question adding something in plus. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a direct translation into C++, but if you do this the program will probably be difficult to maintain and slow. Just remember that all methods are virtual by default, objects are passed by pointer, and `vector` substitutes `ArrayList`:

```
virtual vector<nod*> *getCale(vector<nod*> *lnoduri) {
    lnoduri->insert(lnoduri->begin(), this);
    if (parent != nullptr) lnoduri = parent->getCale(lnoduri);
    return lnoduri;
}

virtual vector<nod*> *getCale() {
    return getCale(new vector<nod*>());
}
```